# AngularJS call compile after compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="theapp">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>asd</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var mainScope;
 angular.module('theapp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {
   $scope.demo = "test123";
   $scope.scopecomp = function(){
  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
   $compile(document.body)($scope);
  });
   }
   mainScope = $scope;
 });
 function addDiv(){
  var $newDiv = $('<div>{{demo}}</div>');
  $(document.body).append($newDiv);
 }
 function comp(){
  mainScope.comp();
 }
 </script>
</head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-change="comp();">
  <h1>{{demo}}</h1>
  <input type="text" id="compText" />
  <button onclick="addDiv();">add</button>
  <button ng-click="scopecomp();">compile with ng-click (works fine)</button>
  <button onclick="comp();">compile with onlick (not working)</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to run the comp() function anywhere in my project. I tried button onclick,it didn't work but ng-click works fine. What is the problem ? Why onclick doesn't work ?

---

### New : changeContent function added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="theapp">
 <head ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>asd</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("theapp", []).controller("MainCtrl", MainController);
  MainController.$injector = ['$timeout'];
  var vm;
  function MainController($timeout) {
   vm = this;
   vm.post = null;
   function loadStuff(){
    $timeout(function() {
     vm.post = {
      title: "Post Title",
      content: "Post Content"
     };
    }, 1000);
   }
   loadStuff();
   
  }
  function changeContent(){
   vm.post.content = "<div>new content </div>";
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p ng-hide="main.post">Loading...</p>
  <h3>{{main.post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{main.post.content}}</p>
  <button onclick="changeContent();">change</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

New bodyController()

```js
function bodyController($scope, $injector) {
 _bodyController = this;
 $scope.title = "ttt";
 $scope.content = "aaa";
 $scope.comp = function(){
  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
   $compile(document.body)($scope);
  });
 }
 myAPP.Run(function(){
  $scope.title = globalOBJ.title;
  $scope.content = globalOBJ.content;
  $scope.comp();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your '' to this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-model="demo" ng-change="comp();">
```

If you check the url from the first line of the error log: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange. The problem is explained:

> Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be
>   found! Description This error occurs when HTML compiler tries to
>   process a directive that specifies the require option in a directive
>   definition, but the required directive controller is not present on
>   the current DOM element (or its ancestor element, if ^ was specified).
>
> To resolve this error ensure that there is no typo in the required
>   controller name and that the required directive controller is present
>   on the current element.

The directive 'ng-change' require a 'ng-model' to work properly, that is why you are getting an compile error.

Now your second question, "Why onclick doesn't work ?". You should never manipulate the DOM from the controller, if you have to do that use a directive. When you call "scopecomp()" from the ng-click that method is invoked from "within" the angular engine, it will fire an *digest cycle* which will process the "html" (it's more than that, I'm trying to keep it simple) and print what you expect, but when you add "{{demo}}" directly to the DOM, that variable will not be processed.

There is no need to change the DOM manually to do what you are looking for, check the snippet below. I simulated your "database request" with a timeout function.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("MainController", MainController);

MainController.$injector = ['$timeout'];
function MainController($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.post = null;
    
  function loadStuff() {
    $timeout(function() {
      vm.post = {
        title: "Post Title",
        content: "Post Content"
      };
    }, 1000);
  }
  loadStuff();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <p ng-hide="main.post">Loading...</p>
  <h3>{{main.post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{main.post.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me an example : I want to recompile body when it is changed ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a better way

Comment: I'm making a project which uses database. After documents load, I have to wait when database requests are responsed. If it respose, i will get a json data like {title:"mytitle",content:"post content"}. Then, the scope gets this data and calls post.html (the body element in this file. For example, if data type is page, my function calls page.html) If all complete, I have to compile the called html file.

Comment: Checkout the snippet I added to the question, there is no need to change da DOM manually to accomplish what you are looking for (if I got it right)

Comment: Thank you for your documents but the project is realtime. I have to recompile body element. How can do that (I gave you +1)

Comment: @cemsinagüzel the code I presented to you is "realtime", you just need to make your server request inside "loadStuff" and change the value of "vm.post"... how are you making the request?

Comment: function loadStuff(){
  myAPP.Run();
 }
===========================
myAPP.Run => gets config from database with callback and goes => myAPP.ConfigsLoaded() => config variables defining and goes => myAPP.LoadPage() => gets some config for database query and goes => myAPP.LoadDATA() => gets data from database and goes => myAPP.LoadView() => gets the HTML file by data type (post,page,category etc.) and goes => myAPP.PageLoaded => empty function (maybe use it later)

Comment: Please, add that peace of code to you post... can't read it like that... but it is very simple... when you get the html content (whenever you get it) set it to "post.content"

Comment: I added a code (your code + changeContent function). When I call the function. It won't change.

Comment: @cemsinagüzel you are not suppose to use "onclick" if you want to interact with angular, if you do want to interact with angular use "ng-click". Angular "run in a separate world"

Comment: All i need is a function compileData(htmlString){
code....
return compiled_data
}
Ex : compile("{{title}}") => myTitle
And i have to call it anywhere in my project and anytime.

Comment: If you want to use angular, you should use angular... if you don't want to things in the "angular way", why are you using it? You are trying to make a workaround to allow angular to "act" instead of using angular directly

Comment: What do you think about the last code (I added a bodyController) ? Now,the problem is comp function not working in the myAPP.Run function. If I call the comp with button ng-click, it works. But I want to auto comp.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$FirebaseJS.Run(function(){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.obj = globalOBJ;
  });
 });
```

Finally I got it.